# Pre diabetic after fasting blood work?

Tags: blood-tests, fatigue, fasting, fodmap, glycemic-index

So I have been feeling very lethargic the past year and went in to get some blood work.  I fasted for 12 hours prior to test, with the exception of mint that I had that morning hour before test that had sorbitol and less than a gram of sugar.

I'm in terrific shape and have a squeaky clean diet (FODMAP for the past 2 years because its easy on my stomach) yet my blood sugar levels came back at 106 mg/dL and that is considered pre diabetic when you're fasting.  Normal is 65-99 mg/dL.

So do you believe that the mint heightened my blood sugar that much that I should retake the test?

I have not spoken to my doctor about it yet (results emailed to me) and have been trying to do some research prior so I can be prepared to have any additional questions.

Thanks in advance!

**Edit**

Not sure if it matters, but I'm 185 lbs, 7.5% body fat and workout 6 days per week.  From all that I read, it looks like the results indicate that I'm moving towards type 2 diabetes?  Better yet, the best way to prevent it is to eat healthy and exercise more.  I could break down my diet easily since I eat the same thing daily and record calories, fat, carbs, protein and it's all low on the glycemic index :(

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Retest**

I generally retest and don't base decisions on a single reading. Although the impact of the mint would seem minimal, the abnormal result itself deserves repeating.

Unfortunately, insulin resistance has become a huge problem and I see it all the time in clinical practice and am no longer surprised when a fit appearing person or an athlete I work with has abnormal glucose metabolism.

Another test(s) to consider would be a fasting insulin and a 2 hour glucose tolerance test. An A1C can be useful combined with other tests.

The approach to figuring out your actual question - Am I pre-diabetic? hinges on the viewpoint of the treating physician.

From a functional medicine approach, normal is often pathologic.  For example, using a normal A1C to exclude insulin resistance and prediabetes will miss a large number of people already in trouble.

Glucose tolerance testing is considered gold standard by many functional medicine experts. A 2-hour reading of 120-139 indicated >60% loss of pancreas Beta cell function (decreased insulin production). A 1-hour 120 or above indicates insulin resistance.

Lipids are also important in determining the risk and using a ratio of triglycerides to HDL (good cholesterol) can help identify insulin resistance.

reference: 4th International Congress on Prediabetes and Metabolic Syndrome. Madrid

Comment: Thanks Mitchel! I heard of the 2 hour tolerance test and believe that could also be beneficial.  Just want to avoid any future health problems if possible :)

Comment: Absolutely great to have people who are proactive about their health. The insulin resistance issue is massive and the rise in diabetes is tragic but preventable with the right approach.